# How to use a value in Sheet2 in the WHERE clause of QUERY in Sheet2 whose dataset is in Sheet1

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Sheet1 that I want to use as my dataset for a Google Spreadsheet query that looks as follows:

[image: Sheet1]

The query is in Sheet 2 and I want to pull across a list of manufacturers who have a Type that matches the value in Sheet2:A1. 
The query I currently have isn't working but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

The value in Sheet2!A1 was copy and pasted from Sheet1!C4 so should be identical.

Spreadsheet can be found at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RP5U16TMbTdZngjrJhGfJxzeLNLapOl9zScQtb2PFLE/edit?usp=sharing

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Thank you. Now, using =QUERY(Sheet1!A2:C4, "SELECT A WHERE C='&A1&'", 1) it returns Ford. It should return  Mercedes which is the only row with Compact in column C ?

Comment: @NickWeavers Please update your question to show your progress and current state of the problem to be solved.

Comment: Thanks @l'-'l. I see that if the data-set rows start below the header you need 0 not 1 as third QUERY param, but when I change it to 0 I get a "Query completed with empty output" result. I copy and pasted Sheet2!A1 to Sheet1!C4 so they should be identical.

Comment: Question updated to show progress @Rubén - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @NickWeavers The spreadsheet requires to ask permission. Please share it with anyone with the link to view.

Comment: @Rubén - new shared link created with view allowed for anyone.

Comment: Just found this post https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67649/list-all-records-with-certain-criteria and tried using "contains" as it does - it worked: =query(Sheet1!A2:C4, "select A where C contains '"&$A1&"'",0)

Comment: However, I don't see why '=' doesn't work, since Sheet1!C4 exactyt matches Sheet2!A1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:C4, "SELECT A WHERE C='"&A1&"'",0)
```